# Add a value to Django's date input settings

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to add a specific date format to the [`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) setting. Now, there is already a default value (a list of formats) for `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` - and I want to append my format to that list.

What is the best way to go about this? Of course, I'm trying to avoid overriding the default definition.

Comment: So you want to avoid editing the `settings.py` file?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, I'm open to editing `settings.py`. What I don't want to do is something like `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['my-format']` and then lose it's default values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **default settings** are stored in **`django.conf.global_settings`**. So in your `settings.py` file you can write:

```
# settings.py

import django.conf.global_settings

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    *django.conf.global_settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
    'Your-extra-format'
]
```

Note that aterisk (`*`) in the list to "unpack" the default list in the new list.

Comment: Thanks Willem, this makes a lot of sense. Something I was thinking of doing is `import django.conf.settings`, and then using `settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`. I assume this is just a better way of doing that (since `settings` is resolved at runtime)?

Comment: @Anomitra: well `settings` is some sort of "end product" of your `settings.py` file: and this thus would construct a "cyclic reference". Django will load the settings, and make them immutable.